# Update textbox value with keypress using Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I am new to Android development. I am trying to create one key that, when clicked, the value is printed in a textbox.

In [this example](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) I find `res->xml->keyboard.xml` file:

```
<Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
```

This prints the digit `1` on the textbox. I want to print "A" on textbox. I tried this:

```
<Key android:text="A" android:keyLabel="A" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
```

but it's not working. How can I do this? Help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`android:keyOutputText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android%3akeyOutputText) instead of `android:text`.

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="A" android:keyLabel="A" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
```

But this only works if you implement the `onText` method in the `BasicOnKeybordActionListener` in the example you linked to.

For example: If you use following implementation, "A" will be logged.

```
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    Log.d("keyboard", text.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you just want to print one character you could also use [key codes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#keycode) with the `android:codes` attribute.

Comment: here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#keycode you can find the possible values as a substitute for X in the following example. `<Key android:codes="X" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />` For an A this would be `<Key android:codes="29" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />`

Comment: If you want to get `android:keyOutputText` to work, i assume you have to implement the `onText(CharSequence)` method of your `OnKeyboardActionListener`. In the case of the [example](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) you linked to this would be in the `it.anddev.tutorial.BasicOnKeyboardActionListener` class.